# Automatic hyperparameter tuning in Sagemaker aws failed to run

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using SageMaker to train my model. And to have better results i'm trying to run the **automatic hyperparameters tuning**. **The training without using this method is running just fine** and giving the result needed, but once I try to run it using this method it gives me and error that is similar to the following error in training jobs (num_filters and learning_rate change):

```
algorithmerror: ExecuteUserScriptError: Command "/usr/bin/python3 script_unet.py --batch_size 54 --learning_rate 0.0002596573898074083
--model_dir s3://sagemaker-us-east-2-6713267672/tensorflow-training-2020-07-04-10-02-56-198/model/tensorflow-training-200704-1002-002-b7291d39/model --num_filters 46"
```

I have tried many other batch sizes just to be sure that it is not a memory problem and It always gives the same error, so i guess it's not.
I need a h5 model extension to use it externally, that is why i'm using that saving lines to a bucket named models-pfe.

The model script i'm using is the following:

```
#Dependencies:
import argparse, os
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.core import Dropout, Lambda
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError

print("All the dependencies imported")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=60)
    parser.add_argument('--num_filters', type=int, default=32)
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.0001)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=64)
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str, default='s3://model-pfe')
    parser.add_argument('--training', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING'])
    parser.add_argument('--testing', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TESTING'])
    parser.add_argument('--access_key', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--secret_key', type=str)



    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    epochs       = args.epochs
    num_filters  = args.num_filters
    lr           = args.learning_rate
    batch_size   = args.batch_size
    model_dir    = args.model_dir
    training_dir = args.training
    testing_dir  = args.testing
    access_key  = args.access_key
    secret_key  = args.secret_key



    X_train = np.load(os.path.join(training_dir, 'training.npz'))['image']
    Y_train = np.load(os.path.join(training_dir, 'training.npz'))['label']
    X_test  = np.load(os.path.join(testing_dir, 'testing.npz'))['image']
    Y_test  = np.load(os.path.join(testing_dir, 'testing.npz'))['label']

    # input image dimensions
    img_rows, img_cols = 512,512

    # Tensorflow needs image channels last, e.g. (batch size, width, height, channels)
    K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
    print(K.image_data_format())



    print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
    print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
    print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

    # Normalize pixel values
    X_train   = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test    = X_test.astype('float32')
    X_train  /= 255
    X_test   /= 255


    # U-Net model
    inputs = Input((512, 512, 3))
    c1 = Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (inputs)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

    c2 = Conv2D(num_filters*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
    c2 = Conv2D(num_filters*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(num_filters*4, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2) (c3)
    c3 = Conv2D(num_filters*4, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(num_filters*8, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2) (c4)
    c4 = Conv2D(num_filters*8, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(num_filters*16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3) (c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(num_filters*16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c5)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters*8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(num_filters*8, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2) (c6)
    c6 = Conv2D(num_filters*8, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters*4, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(num_filters*4, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2) (c7)
    c7 = Conv2D(num_filters*4, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters*2, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(num_filters*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1) (c8)
    c8 = Conv2D(num_filters*2, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
    c9 = Conv2D(num_filters, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    print(model.summary())

    # Use GPUs (for ml.p2.8xlarge = 8 GPUs)
    model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=8)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=lr), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    #Fit model
    results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                        validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        verbose=1,
                        shuffle=True)

    
    # Validation evaluation
    score= model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
    print('Validation loss    :', score[0])
    print('Validation accuracy:', score[1])

    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
    
    def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
        try:
            s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
            print("Upload Successful")
            return True
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("The file was not found")
            return False
        except NoCredentialsError:
            print("Credentials not available")
            return False
    model.save('model.h5')
    upload_to_aws('model.h5','models-pfe',"model.h5")
```

and to run this script on the automatic hyperparameters tuning i'm using the following script:

```
import sagemaker
sess = sagemaker.Session()
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

#My data location in s3
training_input_path="s3://sagemaker-us-east-2-6713267672/pfe-unet/training/training.npz"
validation_input_path="s3://sagemaker-us-east-2-6713267672/pfe-unet/validation/testing.npz"


from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='script_unet.py', 
                          role=role,
                          train_instance_count=1, 
                          train_instance_type='ml.p2.8xlarge',
                          framework_version='1.12', 
                          py_version='py3',
                          script_mode=True,
                          hyperparameters={
                              'epochs': 60,
                              'batch_size': 32, 
                              'access_key'   : '',
                              'secret_key'   : ''}
                         )
from sagemaker.tuner import IntegerParameter, CategoricalParameter, ContinuousParameter, HyperparameterTuner

hyperparameter_ranges = {
    'num_filters'  : IntegerParameter(32,64),
    'learning_rate': ContinuousParameter(0.0001, 0.005)}

objective_metric_name = 'loss'
objective_type = 'Minimize'
metric_definitions = [{'Name': 'loss','Regex': 'loss = ([0-9\\.]+)'}]

tuner = HyperparameterTuner(tf_estimator,
                            objective_metric_name,
                            hyperparameter_ranges,
                            metric_definitions,
                            max_jobs=6,
                            max_parallel_jobs=1,
                            objective_type=objective_type,
                            early_stopping_type='Auto')

tuner.fit({'training': training_input_path, 'validation': validation_input_path})
```

I have changed my bucket name, secret key and access key for security purposes

Comment: You appeared to have an access key and security key at the bottom, can you ensure you remove this key if it exists in your account

Comment: I wrote a different access and secret keys in the question, it's just to show that i did enter the access and secret keys so that people don't think that i forgot to write them in the code.
Thank you

Comment: Thats no problem just wanted to make sure :)